# Dynamic JSON is not equal to Static JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
    const name = 'My name'
    const age = 25

    const detailsDynamic = {
        'Name': `${name}`,
        'Age': `{age}`
    }

    const detailsStatic = {
        'Name':'My name',
        'Age': 25
    }

    if(detailsDynamic == detailsStatic){
        console.log('Equal details')
    }else{
        console.log('Not equal details')
    }
```

Why this is not the same JSON while  I console it looks the same, but condition fails always to  'Not equal details'
Can someone help?

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: A JavaScript object (what you have) is not the same as JSON (which is a textual data exchange format).

Comment: I have to send a post request with axios but I would read the post parameters from config, while I set the parameters hardcoded it works, but while I call it from config it does not works. However they looks same after console.log. One issue I think is that I Have created a class in nodejs and require('config') file and defined all configParams in constructor, I have a regular method say service() while would create another instance for this. So this.configs dont works in service() I have to make an instance of new class() then it call this.configParams. If this is the issue my axiosnotworking

Comment: You have seen the duplicate at the top…?